# Ubuntu 20.04 apt-get update | The certificate is NOT trusted. The name in the certificate does not match the expected

Tags: apt, 20.04, updates, certificates

I am simply trying to update my environment and therefore want to run `sudo apt-get update` that returns me

```
Ign:5 https://www.scootersoftware.com bcompare4 InRelease                      
Hit:7 https://www.scootersoftware.com bcompare4 Release                        
Hit:9 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal InRelease                 
Ign:1 https://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                     
Err:4 https://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease              
  Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:443 (91.189.88.152). - connect (111: Connection refused)
Ign:2 https://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease             
Ign:3 https://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease           
Hit:6 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease               
Err:11 https://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal Release                      
  Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The name in the certificate does not match the expected.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: X.X.X.X 443]
Err:12 https://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates Release              
  Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The name in the certificate does not match the expected.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: X.X.X.X 443]
Err:13 https://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports Release            
  Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The name in the certificate does not match the expected.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: X.X.X.X 443]
Hit:10 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I found some suggestion that says run `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ca-certificates` but this also returns me like [here](https://pastebin.com/vmbxiDdc).

When I run this `sudo apt-get update --fix-missing`, it also returns like [here](https://pastebin.com/jXkNVbvg)

Looks like the certificate name doesn't match with some expected criteria as said in the terminal. Any suggestions, please?

Comment: It looks like the line that is actually causing the error is this one.  The repository 'http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal Release' no longer has a Release file. Seach this site for a fix to that error may solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by changing the `Download from:` under **Ubuntu Software** to Main Server and then revert to Italia which was my actual server. After rebooting the server, I was able to `get update` and `install` them.